Sending notifications with proper image on the right side (FCM) + NodeJS + Flutter
I want to achieve the following:
having notification received on mobile app , with title , body and an image on the right top corner.
the issue that I encounter now with current setup , is that the image sometimes is showing , sometimes not , and also when it is showing , when extending the notification ( in Android) the image become very big which is not wanted.
I want to achieve something like Twitter is doing and viber , eg
VIBER NOTIFICATION COLLAPSED:
VIBER NOTIFICATION COLLAPSED
VIBER NOTIFICATION EXTENDED
VIBER NOTIFICATION EXTENDED
MyApp Notification collapsed:
MyApp Notification collapsed
MyApp Notification extended:
MyApp Notification extended
I'm sending the notification via NodeJS via :
const sendNotification = async (req, res) => {
  let { title, body, token, data = {}, userID } = req.body;
  if (!title || !token) {
    logger.warn('notificationController-send- Missing required fields in request');
    return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: 'Bad request, check documentation' });
  }
    const message = {
      notification: {
        title,
        body,
        image: 'https://d-fe.mk-go.fr/assets/images/taxi.png'
      },
      android: {
        priority: 'high',
        notification: {
            channelId: 'MKGO-MOBILE-DEV'
        }
      },
      data,
      token: token,
    };
    admin.messaging().send(message)
    .then((response) => {
      logger.info(`Notification sent successfully to the following userId=${userID}`);
      logger.info('response: ', response);
      res.json({ status: 200, message: 'Notification sent successfully' });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      logger.error('notificationController-send- Error occured:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ status: 500, message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    });
};

I want to know what can I do and in which area (flutter or nodeJS) to achieve the goal of this notification style.
thank you
I have tested to use in Flutter as Gemini suggested to have Bitmap etc and it is always having issues with some type are not available etc so i was blocked somehow
